# Python print() displays data in scientific format

Tags: python

I have an existing data given in matrix form (class 'numpy.ndarray'). I have noticed something interesting.
If I do this:

```
print(X_train[1:4,:])
```

the result is:

```
 [[1947.    3.    2.   17.] 
 [1725.    3.    2.   42.] 
 [1959.    3.    2.   15.]]
```

But if I do this:

```
print(X_train[0:4,:])
```

the result is the following:

```
 [[1.24e+03 3.00e+00 1.00e+00 6.40e+01]
 [1.95e+03 3.00e+00 2.00e+00 1.70e+01]
 [1.72e+03 3.00e+00 2.00e+00 4.20e+01]
 [1.96e+03 3.00e+00 2.00e+00 1.50e+01]]
```

So, the only difference is 0:4 instead of 1:4, and the print notation is changed to scientific notation. Why?

Comment: Numpy uses some heuristics to determine what format to use. I suspect your first row might have slightly non-integer values when printed with larger precision (I don't remember specifics). Or perhaps it's the range of values that triggers this. Half-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63515988/inconsistent-precision-printing-numpy-arrays

Comment: Not really sure, since first row data is: 1244.0 3.0 1.0 64.0
So there is no number significantly different too large or too small comparing to data in the second row.

Comment: Interesting, when I try to reproduce this I get the same inconsistency between regular and scientific output - except I get 3 decimals behind the decimal point instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions) to change the way output is displayed.

```
numpy.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```

> If False, then scientific notation is used when absolute value of the
> smallest number is < 1e-4 or the ratio of the maximum absolute value
> to the minimum is > 1e3. The default is False.

Because the larger slice contains 1.0 for the minimum, it just goes over the threshold.